# How to Selectively Stop HTML5 Application Cache from Being Backed up on iCloud?

Tags: ios, html, cordova, sencha-touch-2

How to selectively prevent HTML5 application cache from being Backed up on iCloud using PhoneGap/Cordova for iOS?

I need the LocalStorage and WebSQLite Data to be backed up but HTML5 Application Cache used by the HTML5 manifest file should not be backed up on iCloud using PhoneGap/Cordova for iOS. This is to ensure that "[iOS Data Storage Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/data-storage/)" is followed.

I use Sencha Touch 2 for the HTML5 app, where the HTML5 App Cache some times grows as large as 2 MB.

Comment: Have you determined where the Application Cache stores its file(s) in the app's sandbox?

Comment: The file where the Application Cache is stored is same as the localstorage file. In my case it looks something like this: `~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/412CF93A-DD75-11E1-B5D9-5FC560E0EE21/Library/Caches/file__0.localstorage`

Comment: The problem is the application cache is not stored separately from the localstorage. So if I "un-backup" the app cache, it means I "un-backup" the localstorage which could contain other intended application settings or application data. Any solutions for this?